# Replace letters in a string with numbers depending on the letter with Character class

Tags: java, loops, switch-statement, character, charat

I am trying to write a program that accepts a phone number with letters in it and outputs the phone number with all digits. The digits that replace the letter are determined by the following key.

```
0 = none | 1 = none | 2 = ABC
3 = DEF  | 4 = GHI  | 5 = JKL
6 = MNO  | 7 = PQRS | 8 = TUV
         | 9 = WXYZ |
```

So if I got the phone number:

```
1-800-KILLERS
```

The output would be:

```
1-800-545-5377
```

This is what I have so far. I haven't written out all of the cases for the switch statement but they would all go along the lines of the first cases, a,b and c.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Scanner stdin = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.println("Enter a phone number or quit to exit");
    String number = stdin.nextLine();
    System.out.println(getNumber(number));
}

public static int getNumber(String num) {
   for (int i = 0; i < num.length() ; i++) {
       if (Character.isLetter(i) ) {
           switch (num.charAt(i)) {
               case 'A':
               case 'C':
                    num.charAt(i) = "2" ;
                    break;
               // etc
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: consider creating a map where the key is the char and the value is the number

Comment: BTW what is your question?

Comment: Use a `StringBuilder`, so that you can use [`setCharAt`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/StringBuilder.html#setCharAt(int,%20char)). When you're finished, call `toString`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner stdin = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("Programmed By Jason Silva");
        System.out.println();
        System.out.println("Enter a phone number or quit to exit");
        String number = stdin.nextLine();
        System.out.println(getNumber(number));
        stdin.close();
    }

    public static String getNumber(String numString) {
        StringBuilder numStrBuilder = new StringBuilder(); // I used StringBuilder because String is Immutable.
        for (int i = 0; i < numString.length(); i++) {
            char tempChar = numString.toUpperCase().charAt(i); // declared it to block variable for ease of use.
            if (Character.isLetter(tempChar)) {
                switch (tempChar) {
                case 'A':
                case 'B':
                case 'C':
                numStrBuilder.append("2"); // Append this value to StringBuilder if the character is a Letter.
                    break;
                case 'D':
                case 'E':
                case 'F':
                numStrBuilder.append("3");
                    break;
                case 'G':
                case 'H':
                case 'I':
                numStrBuilder.append("4");
                    break;
                case 'J':
                case 'K':
                case 'L':
                numStrBuilder.append("5");
                    break;
                case 'M':
                case 'N':
                case 'O':
                numStrBuilder.append("6");
                    break;
                case 'P':
                case 'Q':
                case 'R':
                case 'S':
                numStrBuilder.append("7");
                    break;
                case 'T':
                case 'U':
                case 'V':
                numStrBuilder.append("8");
                    break;
                case 'W':
                case 'X':
                case 'Y':
                case 'Z':
                numStrBuilder.append("9");
                    break;
                }
            } else {
                numStrBuilder.append(tempChar); // Append the current character if it's not a letter.
            }

            if(i==8) {
                numStrBuilder.append("-"); // Append 'dash' whenever it reaches the 8th element of the String for formatting.
            }
        }
        return numStrBuilder.toString(); // Return it to String because you can't have character like 'dash' in a int.
}
```

Try this. It will work. I used `StringBuilder` as @ScaryWombat says because `String` are `immutable`, means there are many memory allocations that has been wasted if you `concat` many Strings simultaneously.

Answer (score 0):

You have the function rightly created

Create a string

`String str = "";`

If the character at String is a number than go through the switch case

```
if (Character.isLetter(i) ) {

            switch (num.charAt(i)) {

            case 'A':
            case 'B':
            case 'C':
                str  += "2" ;
                break;
```

`else`

`str += number.charAt(i);`

I think this should work fine

PS: Change your return type to string, but if you want it as a number you can call the function inside a loop and send one character a time to get an integer back instead creating a loop inside function

Comment: what question are you answering?

Comment: I think he is solving the problem without question, but this answer makes sense.

Comment: @ScaryWombat I thought he wanted to know what he shoud be doing next. The question is confusing i tried my best to answer it

Comment: Hmm, I wouldn't use a String though

Comment: yeah I would prefer StringBuilder as @ScaryWombat says to append Strings.

Answer (score 0):

Use a map and stream the chars through a conversion:

```
private static Map<Integer, Integer> map = new HashMap<Integer, Integer>() {{
    put('A', '2');
    put('B', '2');
    // etc for C through Y
    put('Z', '9');
}};

static String toNumbers(String input) {
    return input.chars()
      .map(c -> map.getOrDefault(c, c))
      .mapToObj(c -> String.valueOf((char)c))
      .collect(Collectors.joining());
}
```

This (1 line) method converts only the letters, preserving all non-letter characters such as numerals, spaces, hyphens, brackets etc, which as commonly used when entering telephone numbers.

Note that `chars()` returns an `IntStream` (not a `Stream<Character>` as you might expect).

Answer (score 0):

@Jason_Silva you can look at below code it will work for all conditions and all type of inputs as asked in above description.

```
  public class Demo2
  {
  static int i;
  static String str1;
  public static void main(String[] args) {
  Scanner sc=new Scanner(System.in);
  System.out.println("Enter a series");
  String data=sc.nextLine();
  System.out.println(mtd(data));
  }

  public static String mtd(String str){
  for( i=0;i<str.length();i++){
    if(i==9){
        str=str.substring(0,9)+"-"+str.substring(9,str.length());
    }
    if(str.charAt(i)=='A'||str.charAt(i)=='B'||str.charAt(i)=='C'){
      str=str.replace(str.charAt(i),'2');

    }
    if(str.charAt(i)=='J'||str.charAt(i)=='K'||str.charAt(i)=='L'){
          str=str.replace(str.charAt(i),'5');

        }
    if(str.charAt(i)=='T'||str.charAt(i)=='U'||str.charAt(i)=='V'){
          str=str.replace(str.charAt(i),'8');

        }
    if(str.charAt(i)=='J'||str.charAt(i)=='K'||str.charAt(i)=='L'){
          str=str.replace(str.charAt(i),'5');

        }
            if(str.charAt(i)=='G'||str.charAt(i)=='I'||str.charAt(i)=='H'){
          str=str.replace(str.charAt(i),'4');

        }
            if(str.charAt(i)=='P'||str.charAt(i)=='Q'||str.charAt(i)=='R'||str.charAt(i)=='S'){
          str=str.replace(str.charAt(i),'7');

        }
    if(str.charAt(i)=='W'||str.charAt(i)=='X'||str.charAt(i)=='Y'||str.charAt(i)=='Z'){
          str=str.replace(str.charAt(i),'9');

        }

    if(str.charAt(i)=='D'||str.charAt(i)=='E'||str.charAt(i)=='F'){
          str=str.replace(str.charAt(i),'3');

        }
    if(str.charAt(i)=='M'||str.charAt(i)=='N'||str.charAt(i)=='O'){
          str=str.replace(str.charAt(i),'6');

        }
else if(str.charAt(i)>=0 && str.charAt(i)<=9){
    break;
}
else if(str.charAt(i)!='-' && str.charAt(i)<'0' ||str.charAt(i)>'9' || str.charAt(i)>='a' && str.charAt(i)<='z'){
    String data=Character.toString(str.charAt(i));
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder(str);
    sb.deleteCharAt(i);
    str=sb.toString();
    i=i-1;
}
}
return str; 
}
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Define a map which has a character as key and the number as value like this for example:

```
HashMap<Character, Integer> map = new HashMap<Character, Integer>();
map.put('A', 2);
map.put('B', 2);
map.put('C', 2);
map.put('D', 3);
.
.
.
for ( int i = 0; i < num.length() ; i++)
{           
    if (Character.isLetter(num.charAt(i))) 
    {
        if (map.containsKey(num.charAt(i)))
        {
            num.replace(i, i + 1, String.valueOf(map.get(num.charAt(i))));
        }
    }           
}
```

Comment: `replace` returns a new String as Strings are immutable.  Consider bulding up a StringBuilder instead